# how to install bower.json and package.json dependencies osx

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

Visual Studio automatically tracks changes in bower.json & package.json whenever you make changes & save the file. It automatically track new changes. But how would I do it on Visual Studio Code on OSX not sure.

I looked a lot on internet but there are absolutely no resource for dotnet core developers(on osx, linux) on internet. Neither Microsoft has anything mentioned in there documentation.

I have added font-awesome dependency in bower.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 3rd party [bower extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.bower) for Visual Studio Code that lets you run the commands more easily from the editor rather than from the terminal, but bower for vs code is not as integrated as it is in Visual Studio.

For general help with dotnet and OSX there are some [tutorials using vs code on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-on-macos) though not many. The docs site is open source in an effort to encourage community contributions on docs for scenarios like this one.